# Issue with jQuery UI resizable with mask

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-resizable

So I have a draggable and resizable div (this part is working correctly) that needs to be masked so you can only see a certain part of the div at any time. For the mask I'm simply using overflow: hidden. My problem is, the resize handlers connected to .img-wrap are hidden underneath the mask and I need to be able to resize .img-wrap while it is masked. Any ideas as to how I can get them above the mask? You'll see in the fiddle below that you can't drag the edges of the div unless they're viewable.

UPDATED with JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yv332/

UPDATE #2: I had a thought to use custom handles that are outside of the element, but apparently they have to be a child of the resizable element.

HTML:

```
<div id="product">
    <div class="img-wrap" style="background-image: url(someImage); width: 469px; height: 469px;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#product {
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
right: 300px;
top: 100px;
z-index: 1;
width: 235px;
height: 469px;
}
.img-wrap {
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: move;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#product .img-wrap").resizable({
    handles: "ne, nw, se, sw",
    aspectRatio: $("#product .img-wrap").width() / $("#product .img-wrap").height()
}).draggable({

});
```

Comment: Not really understanding the question TBH, a jsfiddle.net might help illustrate, however I have hunch that if you pump the `z-index` on the correct elements you'll be sorted.

Comment: Hey Rob, I've added a JSFiddle above.

Comment: Can you show us the mask?

Comment: The mask is just the #product div with the set width and height.

Comment: Ah right, yes, that's not possible AFAIK with your setup :(

Comment: Something like this seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/yv332/1/

Comment: Thanks for your help Rob, but in that fiddle you still can't resize the NE and SE corners.

Comment: Come'on you didn't think I'd make it that easy for ya?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an other mask(s), you can set the `pointer-events:none;` CSS property on them and get what you're looking for.

HTML:

```
<div id="product">
    <div class="my-mask left"></div>
    <div class="img-wrap" style="background-image: url(http://scontent-a.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpf1/t51.2885-15/10544275_544597625641458_1507697866_n.jpg); width: 469px; height: 469px;"></div>
    <div class="my-mask right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#product {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 469px;
}
.img-wrap {
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: move;
}
.my-mask {
    height:100%;
    width:25%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    background-color:red;
    pointer-events:none;
    z-index:2
}
.left {
    left:0px;
}
.right {
    right:0px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/2x2LB/

Comment: The problem with this is that you still can't get to the edges of the image to resize them when they're not visible.

Comment: You can in chrome and FF? http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/2x2LB/1/ I have lowered opacity of `mask` to let you see.  The `product` div might need to be made bigger height-wise.